# Flutter Textformfield search receives data but does not display other data

Tags: flutter, api, dart

This is my search code. It works by typing id the codes to display the information.

```
onSearch(String text) async {
if (text.isNotEmpty) {
  List<Item> itemList = [];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (item.custnum == text.toLowerCase().toUpperCase()) {
      itemList.add(item);
    }
  }
  setState(() {
    searchitems.clear();
    searchitems.addAll(itemList);
    print('name : ${searchitems[0].name}');
    // if (searchitems.isEmpty) {
    //   searchitems = [];
    // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!.length}');
    // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!}');
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    searchCus.clear();
    searchitems.clear();

    // searchitems.addAll(items);
    print('searchitems : $searchitems');
  });
}
}
```

This is my textformfield, it can find and display data. But what I will do is Getting a code from another page It's received and shows the code. But it doesn't show me the information. It has to delete and type at least 1 new password to show the information. Please help me i tried a lot.

```
TextFormField(
    initialValue:
        '${searchCus.isEmpty ? "" : searchCus[widget.indexCus].custnum}',
        onChanged: onSearch,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'custnum',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'supermarket', fontSize: 14),
            isDense: true,
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: how do you receive the code from the other page and put it in TextFormField?

Comment: initialValue: '${searchCus.isEmpty ? "" : searchCus[widget.indexCus].custnum}', 

I received information from Another search page comes like this. It shows in the textfield, but it doesn't search.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the initial value not do the search is that you search logic is only works when you type in the `textfield`, if your initial value come from class constructor you can call `onSearch` in `initState` like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  if(searchCus.isNotEmpty){
    onSearch(searchCus[widget.indexCus].custnum);
  }
 
}
```

Comment: But I have another problem. I press the clear button You have to press twice to delete the id message .

This is code clear button
 onPressed: () {
              onSearch('');

              _formKey.currentState?.reset();
            },

Comment: this is not related to this question, please open new question and include all related information there.